# How to allow standard user access windows server locally

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We've setup first Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials edition. Our office is small & sometimes fellow users may use server as a workstation. 
By default, only Administrative accounts can login directly/locally to the server in 2012 R2. 
How can I allow standard users access server directly,( or via LAN RDP)?

Answer (score 7):

1. Don't use a server as a workstation.
2. Modify the `Allow logon locally` and/or the `Allow logon through Remote Desktop Services` User Rights Assignment accordingly, either through the Local Security Policy or through Group Policy.

Comment: Don't forget rule 3. Don't use a server as a workstation.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6aec0d9b-b584-41d1-9a4d-5216d696f71d/window-server-essentials-2012-rc-standard-user-login) explains how you can do this...But as joeqwerty said, don't use a server as a workstation especially if that server is running critical processes like an email server.